# python app not starting in visual studio

Tags: python, django, visual-studio

I have created django python app, and when I press F5 , it pops up a python shell which says

```
 Available subcommands:

[auth]
changepassword
createsuperuser

[django]
check
compilemessages
createcachetable
dbshell
diffsettings
dumpdata
flush
inspectdb
loaddata
makemessages
makemigrations
migrate
runfcgi
shell
showmigrations
sql
sqlall
sqlclear
sqlcustom
sqldropindexes
sqlflush
sqlindexes
sqlmigrate
sqlsequencereset
squashmigrations
startapp
startproject
syncdb
test
testserver
validate

[sessions]
clearsessions

[staticfiles]
collectstatic
findstatic
runserver
Press any key to continue . . .
```

But it does not open any browser and app is not running, when I hit any key , it just stops the app.

I am wondering what is the issue. Weird thing is few days ago this app was working fine and I didn't do anything after that.

Comment: if you work with Django you have to run it manual, go into the terminal and type python manage.py runserver

Comment: are you able to use [these commands](https://djangobook.com/developing-django-visual-studio/#leanpub-auto-integration-of-django-management-commands) to start the server..

Comment: @MauricioCortazar I have run it earlier from VStudio, n ot sure what is the issue now.

Comment: @PRMoureu Yes, I am able to migrate and also able to create superuser.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved the issue. The issue was with the port 8000, my system was not allowing me to access port number: 8000.

So I went to VisualStudio ---->Debug ----> Project properties at bottom ---> Debug --->enter port number : 5000

and then it worked like charm.